# Counting Contiguous Sets of Data provided no other sets occur within 500 rows

Tags: vba

I want to write some VBA code that will count how many sets of "contiguous rows of Ts" there are in a single column in a worksheet.  However I want such data sets to only be counted if there are more than 500 rows after the final **T** in a set that contain **F** values.  For example, if **T** values are found at rows 500-510, then rows 511- 1010 would have to contain **F** values for one to be added to the count.  If another T is encountered before reaching 1010, then the code would "reset" the 500 row counter and begin again.

```
row 1 - 1000 = F
row 1001 - 1011 = T
row 1012 - 1600 = F
row 1601 - 1611 = T
row 1612 - 3000 = F
```

In this case the counter would display **2**

Conversely:

```
row 1 - 1000 = F
row 1001 - 1011 = T
row 1012 - 1400 = F
row 1401 - 1411 = T
row 1412 - 3000 = F
```

The counter would only display **1** as the Ts in cluster 1001-1011 are <500 rows within cluster 1401-1411.

I am also aware that in some scenarios there may be a set of Ts that are within 500 rows of the end of overall data.  These would also need to be ignored from the count (I.e. using the example above, if Ts occurred a 2,700 - 2710, in a set of data with 3,000 rows, these would need to be ignored from the count).  Similarly I would need to exclude rows 1-500 from the count also.

I don't know if this would be possible or even how to begin writing the code for this, so any assistance will be greatly appreciated.  Excerpt of data:

```
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
T
T
T
T
T
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
F
```

This is going to be added to a much larger macro which then goes to filter out all rows containing Ts and deleting them.  However I want to perform the count of contiguous Ts first before taking this step.

Code for rest of macro (This code is called by another macro which takes the values generated and pastes them into a master file):

```
Sub RollMap_Ensocoat(Wb As Workbook)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim finalRow As Long

'Set name of first sheet in spreadsheet to "1"

With Wb.Sheets(1)

        .Name = "1"

End With

'Code to delete all rows that contain a "T" in column G" (Indicating a tab was fired and thus is waste)

    With Sheets("1")

        finalRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("G4:G" & finalRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="T"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

 'Code to calculate all the important values of each reel that will be pasted into the master report.

    End With

    Set ws = Wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count))

    With ws
        .Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX('1'!C)"
        .Range("B3").Formula = "=A3*I3"
        .Range("C3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!B4:B10000)"
        .Range("D3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!C4:C10000)"
        .Range("E3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!D4:D10000)"
        .Range("F3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!E4:E10000)"
        .Range("G3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!F4:F10000)"
        .Range("H3").Formula = "=SUM(C3:G3)"
        .Range("I3").Formula = "='1'!A1"
        .Range("J3").Formula = "=H3/(A3*I3)"
        .Range("K3").Value = "0.21"
        .Range("L3").Value = Wb.Name
        .Range("M3").Formula = "=Left(L3, Len(L3) - 4)"
        .Range("M3").Copy
        .Range("M3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("N3").Formula = "=RIGHT(M3, 11)"
        .Range("O3").Formula = "=LEFT(N3,2) & ""/"" & MID(N3,3,2) &  ""/20"" & MID(N3,5,2)"
        .Range("P3").Formula = "=MID(N3,8,2)& "":"" & MID(N3,10,2)"
        .Range("Q3").Formula = "=Left(L3, Len(L3) - 16)"
        .Range("A3:Q3").Copy
        .Range("A3:Q3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("A3:Q3").Copy

    End With

End Sub
```

Code with Tim's suggested additions:

```
Sub Populate_Ensocoat()

On Error GoTo eh

Dim MyBook As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFil As String
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim xCount As Long
Dim SourceRang1 As Range
Dim FillRange1 As Range

'Code to improve performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Code to Prompt user to select file location
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
End With

'Code to count how many files are in folder and ask user if they wish to continue based on value counted

strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv*")

Do While strFil <> ""
xCount = xCount + 1
strFil = Dir()
Loop

If MsgBox("You have selected " & xCount & " files.  Are you sure you wish to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then GoTo eh

'Code to Start timer

StartTime = Timer

'Code to make final report sheet visible and launch sheet hidden

Sheet1.Visible = True
Sheet1.Activate
Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = False

'declaring existing open workbook's name

MyBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Code to cycle through all files in folder and paste values into master report

strFil = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv*")

Do While strFil <> vbNullString

Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFil)

    Call RollMap_Ensocoat(Wb)
    Workbooks(MyBook).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    strFil = Dir
Loop

'Formatting of values in final report

Range("B:I").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Range("J:K").NumberFormat = "0.000"
Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Range("P:P").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
Range("Q:Q").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

'Code to add header data to report (i.e. total files, name of person who created report, date and time report was created)

Range("Y2").Value = Now
Range("H2").Value = "# of Files Reported on: " & xCount
Range("P2").Value = Application.UserName

'Re-enabling features disabled for improved macro performance that are now needed to display finished report

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Code to refresh sheet so that graphs display properly

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Code to automatically save report in folder where files are located.  Overrides warning prompting user that file is being saved in Non-macro enabled workbook.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFolder & "\" & "Summary Report", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Code to display message box letting user know the number of files reported on and the time taken.

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

MsgBox "Operation successfully performed on " & xCount & " files in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Report created at location: " & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, vbInformation

Done:
    Exit Sub

eh:
    MsgBox "No Folder Selected.  Please select re-select a board grade"

End Sub


Sub RollMap_Ensocoat(Wb As Workbook)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim finalRow As Long


'Set name of first sheet in spreadsheet to "1"

With Wb.Sheets(1)

        .Name = "1"
        .Range("H1").Formula = "=TCount(G3:G10000)"

End With

'Code to delete all rows that contain a "T" in column G" (Indicating a tab was fired and thus is waste)

    With Sheets("1")

        finalRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("G4:G" & finalRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="T"
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

 'Code to calculate all the important values of each reel that will be pasted into the master report.

    End With

    Set ws = Wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Wb.Sheets.Count))

    With ws
        .Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX('1'!C)"
        .Range("B3").Formula = "=A3*I3"
        .Range("C3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!B4:B10000)"
        .Range("D3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!C4:C10000)"
        .Range("E3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!D4:D10000)"
        .Range("F3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!E4:E10000)"
        .Range("G3").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109,'1'!F4:F10000)"
        .Range("H3").Formula = "=SUM(C3:G3)"
        .Range("I3").Formula = "='1'!A1"
        .Range("J3").Formula = "=H3/(A3*I3)"
        .Range("K3").Value = "0.21"
        .Range("L3").Value = Wb.Name
        .Range("M3").Formula = "=Left(L3, Len(L3) - 4)"
        .Range("M3").Copy
        .Range("M3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("N3").Formula = "=RIGHT(M3, 11)"
        .Range("O3").Formula = "=LEFT(N3,2) & ""/"" & MID(N3,3,2) &  ""/20"" & MID(N3,5,2)"
        .Range("P3").Formula = "=MID(N3,8,2)& "":"" & MID(N3,10,2)"
        .Range("Q3").Formula = "=Left(L3, Len(L3) - 16)"
        .Range("R3").Formula = "='1'!H1"
        .Range("A3:R3").Copy
        .Range("A3:R3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("A3:R3").Copy

    End With

End Sub

Function TCount(rng As Range)
    Const GAP_SIZE As Long = 5 '<< low number for testing...
    Dim rv As Long, i As Long, fCount As Long, n As Long, d
    Dim haveT As Boolean
    rv = 0
    d = rng.Value
    n = UBound(d, 1)
    fCount = 0

    If n > GAP_SIZE Then
        For i = 1 To n
            If d(i, 1) = "T" Then
                fCount = 0
                haveT = True
            Else
                fCount = fCount + 1
                If fCount = GAP_SIZE And haveT Then
                    rv = rv + 1
                    haveT = False
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    TCount = rv
End Function
```

Comment: By "cluster" you mean "contiguous" - i.e. several Ts in a row? Do you have any code yet? Can you get as far as how many Ts running?

Comment: Are T and F the only possible values?  Are any cells blank?

Comment: I do indeed mean contiguous.  I have included the code of the macro I have so far for the other tasks it is already performing well.  T and F are the only possible values.  Basically they correspond to a "True" and "False" states, output by a piece software.  There are no blank cells.

Comment: If there is a collection of Ts that are non-contiguous, but don't have 500 Fs between them, does that count as 0 or 1? Something like this: ...FFF**TT**FFF**TTT**FFFF...

Comment: Hello Caleb, using your example it would count as a 0.

Comment: This would all be easier to visualize and to include examples if you reduced the "F-block" size to (say) 5+ instead of 500+...

Comment: I was thinking more like: `Wb.Sheets(1).Range("H1").Value = TCount(Wb.Sheets(1).Range("G3:G10000"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

You may need to adjust if I made wrong assumptions about your rules.

```
Function TCount(rng As Range)
    Const GAP_SIZE As Long = 5 '<< low number for testing...
    Dim rv As Long, i As Long, fCount As Long, n As Long, d
    Dim haveT As Boolean, earlyT as Boolean
    rv = 0
    d = rng.Value
    n = UBound(d, 1)
    fCount = 0

    If n > GAP_SIZE Then
        For i = 1 To n
            If d(i, 1) = "T" Then
                fCount = 0
                If i <= GAP_SIZE Then earlyT = True '<<EDIT
                haveT = True
            Else
                fCount = fCount + 1
                If fCount = GAP_SIZE And haveT Then
                    rv = rv + 1
                    haveT = False
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    TCount = rv - IIf(earlyT, 1, 0) '<< EDIT
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Tim.  Thank you for this.  My only issue is, is that I can only get it to work if I call the function when in the same workbook.  Currently I have a master sheet which calls the above macro (RollMap_Ensocoat()) and then takes the values generated by the macro and pastes them on the next line in the master spreadsheet.  My memory of custom functions is hazy, but I cannot remember if it is possible to call a function and then use it on another workbook.

Comment: It's not intended as a UDF - just pass it the range of T/F values from your existing VBA, and use the return value.

Comment: Hello Tim.  Whilst I can get this to work if I create a new workbook where I use a simply subroutine to call the function and return a value based on my range.  I cannot get this to work in my existing VBA with a #name? being returned when I try to call the function.  I have added my full code towards the end of my initial post.

Comment: #name isn't something you'd get from this code if you're calling it via VBA: are you calling it from a worksheet cell?

Comment: Hello Tim, still pretty new to calling functions but have finally managed to get it to work!   Got it to work using the following code: `Dim finalRow As Long
Dim Joins As Integer
Dim Rng As Range


        finalRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range("G4:G" & finalRow)
        Joins = TCount(Rng)
        
        .Range("R3").Formula = Joins - 1`  Thank you for the help.  Would there be a way to alter the function however to -1 from the Tcount if a T exists in the first 500 rows of the array?

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: See my edits above for your question about finding a T in the first 500 rows.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, this is going to save me so much time!